# A quick question on graphing Heaviside functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph the function $f(t) = \sin(2(t-\pi))\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is the Heaviside function defined by:

$\mathcal{U}(t-a) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{} t \lt a \\
1 & \mbox{} t \geq a \end{cases}$

I know that $\sin(2(t-\pi))=\sin(2t)$, so I figured $f$ is just a piecewise function that looks like

$f(t) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{} t \lt \pi \\
\sin(2t)& \mbox{} t \geq \pi \end{cases}$

So then $f(t) = \sin(2(t-\pi))\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)$ would simply be the graph of $\sin(2t)$ after $t=\pi$ and $0$ everywhere else? I feel as though I am simplifying this too much.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(2(t-pi))unitstep(t-pi),+-2+pi+%3C%3D+t+%3C%3D+2+pi

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was trying to figure out how to plot the unit step in Wolfram.